# MySql workbench: add Foreign key error

Tags: mysql

I am trying to add foreign key 'USERNAME' in tutorial table, but there was an error.

```
Executing:
ALTER TABLE `databse`.`tutorial`   
ADD CONSTRAINT `USERNAME`
   FOREIGN KEY (`USERNAME`)
   REFERENCES `databse`.`register` (`USERNAME`)
   ON DELETE CASCADE
   ON UPDATE CASCADE;

 Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
 ERROR 1452: Cannot add or update a child row:
a foreign key constraint   fails (`databse`.`#sql-e7c_5`, CONSTRAINT `USERNAME` FOREIGN KEY (`USERNAME`) 
 REFERENCES `register` (`USERNAME`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
 SQL Statement:
  ALTER TABLE `databse`.`tutorial`  
  ADD CONSTRAINT `USERNAME`
  FOREIGN KEY (`USERNAME`)
  REFERENCES `databse`.`register` (`USERNAME`)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Foreign key setting:
[image]

Tutorial table setting: 
[image]

Any ideas ?  thank you

I solved it, i created a new 'tutorials' table replace 'tutorial' table, and use same way to add foreign key, it worked! = =

still thank you for your helps !!

Comment: could you instead **paste** the error rather than taking a capture please?

Comment: Are you sure you created the `register` table before the creation of the `tutorial` table?

Comment: Having everything in a picture removes any usefullness to other people in the future.

Comment: Your current data does not comply with the relationship you want to enforce?

Answer (score 0):

as stated [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) :

> A FOREIGN KEY is a field (or collection of fields) in one table that refers to the PRIMARY KEY in another table.

In the code you show : you try to reference the "USERNAME" column, wich is not a primary key in your last capture

So you can either change your primary key in the `register` table to `USERNAME`, or you can change the foreign key to reference `TutorialName`

Answer (score 0):

You have two table one is child table  and second is parent table .So you would need to guarantee that each child  column has NULL or has values that present in parent column.

Comment: I think you haven't read the question properly... This answer is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is normally caused by mismatching of values presented in the two columns constrained by the new foreign key.

That is, the value presented in the child table does not have a reference presented in the parent table.

when creating a foreign key, you need to make sure that:

1. the table type supports foreign key
2. there is a index on the foreign key column
3. the types of data of the two columns constrained by a foreign key are similar enough so that they can be converted to each other
4. the data presented in both columns constrained by a foreign key is consistent.